# How to compare multiple column with same values (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare multiple values of a table with same set of values in single shot without using multiple `AND` condition in `WHERE` clause. Please let me know is any methods to do it.

### code:

```
select count(1)
  from test
 where pre_sys_id1 in (select sys_id from test where auto_id = 10)
   and pre_sys_id2 in (select sys_id from test where auto_id = 10)
   and pre_sys_id3 in (select sys_id from test where auto_id = 10)
   and pre_sys_id4 in (select sys_id from test where auto_id = 10)
;
```

Comment: How your output should look?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(1)
from test
where  (select sys_id from test where auto_id=10) = all (pre_sys_id1,pre_sys_id2,pre_sys_id3,pre_sys_id4)
```

Or join

```
Select count(1)
from test t1
join test t2 on( sys_id= pre_sys_id1 and sys_id= pre_sys_id2 and sys_id= pre_sys_id3  and sys_id= pre_sys_id4) 
where t2.auto_id = 10 ;
```

Comment: What if `(select sys_id from test where auto_id=10)` returns multiple rows?

Comment: Exception will be raised ( single-row subquery returns more than one row). 
Construction with all/some works only for scalar values. 

`one_value =,<,> ALL/SOME (set of values) `

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
select count(1)
  from test
 where (pre_sys_id1, pre_sys_id2, pre_sys_id3, pre_sys_id4)
   in (select sys_id, sys_id, sys_id, sys_id from test where auto_id = 10)
```